# ValueAnimator duplicate Values when starting

Tags: android, animation

Im Using a ValueAnimator (from [NineOldAndroids](http://www.nineoldandroids.com)) to animate a View in my ViewGroup.

```
ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(mHandleRect.left, mDisplayRect.right - mHandleWidth);
anim.setDuration(delta);
anim.addUpdateListener(onAnimationUpdateListener);                  
anim.addListener(onAnimationListener);
anim.start();
```

In this case from 0 to 402, but i have tried it with other values.

Then i'm using the Values in the Animation Update Listener:

```
@Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            int val = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();

            Log.d("Animation Animating", " Current Value " + val);
}
```

Now, here comes the problem:

The first values are all 0, multiple times

```
04-06 22:24:40.128: D/Animation Animating(22500):  Current Value 0
04-06 22:24:40.128: D/Animation Animating(22500):  Current Value 0
04-06 22:24:40.313: D/Animation Animating(22500):  Current Value 0
04-06 22:24:40.313: D/Animation Animating(22500):  Current Value 0
04-06 22:24:40.323: D/Animation Animating(22500):  Current Value 0
04-06 22:24:40.338: D/Animation Animating(22500):  Current Value 4
04-06 22:24:40.418: D/Animation Animating(22500):  Current Value 66
04-06 22:24:40.448: D/Animation Animating(22500):  Current Value 104
04-06 22:24:40.463: D/Animation Animating(22500):  Current Value 128
04-06 22:24:40.478: D/Animation Animating(22500):  Current Value 152
04-06 22:24:40.493: D/Animation Animating(22500):  Current Value 175
04-06 22:24:40.513: D/Animation Animating(22500):  Current Value 201
04-06 22:24:40.533: D/Animation Animating(22500):  Current Value 232
04-06 22:24:40.548: D/Animation Animating(22500):  Current Value 255
04-06 22:24:40.563: D/Animation Animating(22500):  Current Value 280
04-06 22:24:40.603: D/Animation Animating(22500):  Current Value 335
04-06 22:24:40.628: D/Animation Animating(22500):  Current Value 360
04-06 22:24:40.653: D/Animation Animating(22500):  Current Value 378
04-06 22:24:40.668: D/Animation Animating(22500):  Current Value 389
04-06 22:24:40.698: D/Animation Animating(22500):  Current Value 400
04-06 22:24:40.713: D/Animation Animating(22500):  Current Value 402
```

This results in a delayed and juddery start of the visible Animation.

I have tried to expand the duration and the values, the problem still exists.

Have anyone the same problem, or am i to nit-pick?

Comment: Have you since figured out the reason for this? I'm running into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar issue, but in my case the updated value was varying between the start value and end value.

Try this:

```
   int mPrevious = -1;
    @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                int val = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                if(val != mPrevious){
                Log.d("Animation Animating", " Current Value " + val);                    
                mPrevious = val;
                } 

    }
```

Logic statement should not have any performance or visual hits.

Alternatively you could try to add 0 as delayed time. That will make the animator start animating immediately.

Comment: Thats not the problem. The animation works only with values greater than 0.
The real problem is the delay that is produced by this Animator class.
I have a delay about 200-300ms before the animation really starts.Because of the multiple 0 values.
anim.setStartDelay(0); does not help.