# Android: ObjectAnimator with long duration

Tags: android, objectanimator

im trying to do a seekbar animation, by using ObjectAnimator. The problem is if i set ObjectiAnimator's duration with a large value, it will have a delay of before starting. Here is my code:

```
_replayBar.setMax(FlightLogger.getTimeLength());
_replayBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
_timeMax.setText(secondsToTimeFormat(0) + "/" + secondsToTimeFormat(_replayBar.getMax()));

anim=ObjectAnimator.ofInt(_replayBar, "progress", 0, _replayBar.getMax());
anim.setDuration(_replayBar.getMax() * 1000);
```

where anim is the objectAnimator, _replaybar is the seekbar, and FlightLogger.getTimeLenth() returns the time in milliseconds.

All I am trying to do is make the seekbar update process in real time by second.But if the value that passed to anim.setDuration becomes too large(i.e: 2minutes), it will delay the starting for few seconds. And if the duration goes even larger(i.e: 1 hour), the delay could be few minutes.

I also tried to use ValueAnimator, with similar code, plus the onAnimationUpdate listener as following:

```
anim.addUpdateListener(new ObjectAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        if (!anim.isRunning())
            anim.resume();
        animProgress = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
        Log.d(TAG, "progress: " + valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue());
        _replayBar.setProgress(animProgress);
    }
});
```

I log the process in the listener, and get duplicate values return for every process, similarly to [ValueAnimator duplicate Values when starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899683/valueanimator-duplicate-values-when-starting).

can anyone help me with that?
Many thanks

Comment: how often do you want to change the "progress" property?

Comment: every second, similarly to playing a vedio

Comment: so use `android.os.CountDownTimer` or raw `Handler`, animators are not for such use cases

Comment: ill try it. thanks for ur help

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem with CountDownTimer, thanks for pskink's suggestion.
Here is the timer class:

```
public class BCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer{

    public BCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long l) {
        millisLeft=l;
        int seekBarProgress= _replayBar.getMax()-(int)(l*0.001);
        _replayBar.setProgress(seekBarProgress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        _replayBar.setProgress(_replayBar.getMax());
        isPlaying = false;
        _playPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_btn_play);
        _timer= new BCountDownTimer(_replayBar.getMax()*1000, 1000);
    }
}
```

In order to pause and resume, the millisLeft stores the time left.